# Inherit Attributes from Another Set in Nix Expression Language

Tags: nix, nixos

In Nix manual's [Inheriting attributes](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#idm140737318140176) section, we have

```
graphviz = (import ../tools/graphics/graphviz) {
  inherit fetchurl stdenv libpng libjpeg expat x11 yacc;
  inherit (xlibs) libXaw;
};

xlibs = {
  libX11 = ...;
  libXaw = ...;
  ...
}

libpng = ...;
libjpg = ...;
...
```

What do the brackets around `import ...` (i.e. `(import ../tools/graphics/graphviz)`) do? Also, what do the brackets in `inherit (xlibs) libXaw;` do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`xlibs` is in the same scope as graphviz but `libXaw` is not, because it's inside the `xlibs` set. So to be able to pass it as an argument to the graphviz function you need to explicitly `inherit (xlibs) libXaw`. That behaviour denoted by the brackets is unique to the `inherit` keyword.

The brackets in `(import ../tools/graphics/graphviz)` are simply the common convention for denoting order of evaluation. `import` is a function that accepts a single argument `path`. The file in `../tools/graphics/graphviz` contains a single function that accepts a set of attributes as its argument. So the brackets denote that the order of evaluation should be (1) import the function in `path` then (2) apply the attribute set `{...}` to that function.

---

Edit: @danbst pointed out that in this case the brackets in `import ../tools/graphics/graphviz` aren't needed. The reason for this is that evaluating `import ../tools/graphics/graphviz` returns a function which is then called with the set `{ ... }`.

The necessity of the brackets can be demonstrated by using the same values as arguments for this function `typesOfArgs = one: two: with builtins; "${typeOf one} and ${typeOf two}"` which returns a string. `typesOfArgs (import ../tools/graphics/graphviz) { }` would evaluate to `"lambda and set"` but without the brackets the interpreter would evaluate `typesOfArgs import ../tools/graphics/graphviz` to `"lambda and path"` and then try to call that string as a function with the argument `{ }` which would result in `error: attempt to call something which is not a function but a string`

<strike>Without the brackets the interpreter would assume you want to call the function `import` with the 2 arguments `path` and `{ ... }`, which would be an error.</strike>

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thanks!